# Binomial formula for $(x+1)^{1/3}$ (related to Newton's binomial theorem)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I know that

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{1+x} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{(-1)^{(j-1)}}{2^{2j-1}\cdot(2j-1)}\binom{2j-1}{j}x^j\right). $$

Now, I want to evaluate $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$ but stuck at some point:

To evaluate $\sqrt[3]{1+x}$, I first tried to find what $\binom{1/3}{j}$ is

$$\binom{1/3}{j} = \frac{(1/3 \cdot (1/3-1) \cdot (1/3-2) \cdots (1/3-j+1))}{j!} = \frac{(-1)^{j-1}\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdots (3j-4)}{3^j\cdot j!}$$

However I could not continue from here. Is there a way to write $1\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdots(3j-4)$ in another form? (Or is $3\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdots(3j-5)$ possible?)
Could you please help me?

Regards

Comment: I slightly improved the $\LaTeX$ in your question. Please check that I kept the meaning of the question.

Comment: @GitGud thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think you can write anything for $(2)(5)\cdots(3j-4)$. Why do you feel you need to?

Comment: @GerryMyerson while solving for $\sqrt{1+x}$, there was 1*3*5*7*..*(2j-3) at the nominator, then I multiplied both the nominator and the demoniator with 2*4*6*...*(2j-2) and found the answer. However in this case (cube root), it seems not to be working (multiplying nominator and dominator with 3*4*6*7*9*11*...). So I thought maybe there can be a way to write 2*5*...*(3j-4) in another way. But you are right, I am not sure about what to do in order to solve this problem. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If there isn't a solution, there isn't a problem. Not every complex mathematical expression has a simpler form. I think you have to live with what you have.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But the person who asked me this question told me that he saw this on a book as an exercise problem. So I guess there must be a decent expression?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your main question but there is a typo in the numerator: $-1^{j+1}$ instead of $(-1)^{j+1}$.

Comment: $$ 1.2.5 \ldots (3j-4)= {\frac {{3}^{j-1}\Gamma  \left( j-1/3 \right) }{\Gamma  \left( 2
/3 \right) }}.$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Could you please explain me the meaning of that symbol looks like a sickle?

Comment: @Xentius it's called gamma function.

Comment: @Xentius: It is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  We also have the identity $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$

Thus, we can [generalize the binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments) as:

$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(r + 1)\Gamma(n-r + 1)}$$

Therefore:
$$\binom{1/3}{j} = \frac{\Gamma(4/3)}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j + 2/3)}$$

Note, though, that you may run into some issues, as $r$ (as in, $\binom{n}{r}$) should be in the range $[0, n]$.